# How to connect to Firebase Auth emulator

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a Node.js API that uses Firebase Authentication under the hood with firebase-admin SDK.

- The client makes a GraphQL mutation passing email and password
- The API authenticates the user with Firebase Auth, fetches user info in the database and sends auth token and user info back to the client.

So far, for development, I have been using a Firebase project in the cloud, but I would like to switch to Auth emulator.

I added the auth emulator through the firebase-tools CLI: `firebase init emulators` and selecting Authentication when prompted.

I then start the emulators `firebase emulators:start` and my API server, specifying this environment variable: `FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:9099` as suggested in [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_auth#admin_sdks).

According to the guide, specifying `FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:9099` should be enough for `firebase-admin` to know that it should connect to the emulators. However when I try to authenticate, the API is still using the project in the cloud.

Did anybody run into something similar? Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it didn't work for you, it seems like you did everything well. I can't infer what you did wrong from your posted information, you might have done something like initializing the firebase app with remote info which overrides local requests. Here is some code which worked for me, you should try this solution and derive what you did wrong from this working demo.

## Firebase Emulator

I initialized the emulator as suggested in the [official article](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_and_prototype),
`firebase init` -> `firebase init emulators`, and I picked the relevant picks until I ended up with those files:

**.firebaserc**

```
{}
```

**firebase.json**

```
{
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true,
      "port": 8088
    },
    "singleProjectMode": true
  }
}
```

It's really doesn't matter if you just copy those files instead of initializing the emulator manually with the commands shown above.

Finally, to start up the emulator run `firebase emulators:start --project custom-project-id`

## Node.js App

```
import admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp({ projectId: "custom-project-id" })

admin.auth()
  .createUser({
    displayName: 'John Doe',
    email: 'user@example.com',
    password: 'secretPassword',
  })
  .then((user) => {
    console.log('Successfully created new user:', user);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error creating new user:', error);
  });
```

The JavaScript code is pretty self explanatory. You should initialize firebase app from admin SDK, and give it a project id as same as the one you used for the emulator, and in this example: *custom-project-id*.

As you said, it's important to set environment variable where you run the JS code: `export FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST="localhost:9099"`

After you set it, run `node filename.js` and you should see a success message, along with a detailed user information.

---

This is how you should set the emulator. I hope this will help you, and if it doesn't please let me know so I can try and find the right solution for you.